# Configuring Intel Ironlake to run WoW's OpenGL | Wine1.7

Tags: drivers, graphics, wine, intel, opengl

My current problem is encountering a "Memory could not be read/recognized" something along the lines of that when trying to Start WoW in OpenGL mode.  I am aware that Direct3D is possible, and will run, but it has issues.  I was really shooting for getting OpenGL to work when I wiped my drive for Ubuntu.

Currently running Ubuntu 14.04 (15 was not stable for me...perhaps I'll update later and try again).

Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 380 @ 2.53GHz × 4

I have found nothing on searches in various forums and Google.

Intel® Ironlake Mobile Graphics

3.7 GiB Memory

Edit: This is apparently able to be done, but hasn't been implement by Intel yet. [See article here.](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTMxMDQ)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Ironlake series do not support OpenGL versions later than 2.1.  This is also true in Windows AFAIK.  I suspect that's your problem, and there are no other drivers.  Intel doesn't do binary drivers.